# Image caching in Github?

Tags: github, caching

Is there any **caching policy** of images in GitHub? 
I am facing trouble while rendering an image from an API. The image works fine when I open it in the browser. 
However, Github **renders some older version of that image**.

How can I workaround this issue or is there any fix?

Comment: GitHub is known to aggressively cache images (particularly badges). See: https://github.community/t/how-to-prevent-github-from-caching-images-in-markdown-files/1868

Comment: Can you suggest some workaround ? So that the images are updated there as well ?

Comment: Yes, if you host the images yourself you need to have a web server that allows setting the HTTP response headers as described in the above link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering [this `netlify/netlify-cms` PR](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-cms/pull/449/files#diff-d3cff7a0c66d0acce37277791446d509), maybe adding the `ts=$(date)` as parameter of a [GitHub API v3 call](https://developer.github.com/v3/) would be enough of a "cache busting" for your need.

From the code:

```
const cacheBuster = new Date().getTime();
const params = [`ts=${cacheBuster}`];
if (options.params) {
  for (const key in options.params) {
    params.push(`${ key }=${ encodeURIComponent(options.params[key]) }`);
  }
}
if (params.length) {
  path += `?${ params.join("&") }`;
}
return this.api_root + path;
```

This adds a `&ts=xxx` timestamp parameter to the `api.github.com` call.

Comment: Got it. So basically we are trying to get a new unique URL for every request.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes, a classic technique of cache busting.

Answer (score 1):

You can force image refresh:

```
curl -X PURGE https://camo.githubusercontent.com/BLAHBLAHBLAH
```